# can javascript be used to tell wheather a site is online or not?

Tags: javascript, networking

is it possible for javascript to be used to check whether a site is online, and if it is download a piece of information from said site, or would this require server side code like PHP?

Comment: If that information is static, you can do it without a dinamic language, i mean only json, xml, etc... if not, it will need something like php, asp.net, java etc.

Comment: for example, desiring to display a div from site B within a DIV of site A. however site B may not always be online so it's important to be able to cycle through a list of addresses instead of just displaying the "site unreachable" error